# Class Instance - Create specific count of instance for a class only - Multithreading environment

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

**Need to create specified number of instance for a particular class in JVM**

Like for `Singleton pattern`, we manage and create only 1 instance.

now for suppose `class Abc`, i just want to

1.) create only 3 instances at maximum.

2.) Multithreading environment.

```
class Abc{
  private static Abc abc1;
  private static Abc abc2;
  private static Abc abc3;

private Abc(){

}

 public static synchronized Abc getInstance1(){
        if(abc1 == null){
            abc1 = new Abc();
        }
        return abc1;
    }

: // same as above for abc2
: // same as above for abc3

}
```

** Now problem is suppose i want to increase instance from total 3 to to say 4 or 5 or n number.

Also i do want to expose so many methods `(getInstance1(), getInstance2()... etc)`

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: Not clear. When and where this `n` is supposed to be set?

Comment: @PM77-1 Suppose i make n as configurable, somehow read from properties files, then i have to manage the instances in the JVM.

Comment: In this case you will be better off with a collection of objects and `getInstance(int i)` getters.

Comment: @ankur-singhal - Well, then maintain an `Arraylist<T>` inside your `T` class. Then based on `n`, you can create instances (either lazily or eagerly).. My questions - *should each call to getInstance() return a different instance ?*. *what should happen when you call `n+1` th time?..

Comment: @TheLostMind returning different instance or based on some algorithm, can be a different question, but just wanted to know how to maintain the specific count of instance, i think going with `ArrayList` can be possible.

Comment: @ankur-singhal - Okies. Also, in case you have some *common/ basic* data to be initialized for all instances, you could use *prototype* pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want an instance per thread.

There or out of the box solutions for this, the DI containers like Guice, spring and many other.

If you really want to do this yourself, you could use a map the keep an instance per thread.

```
public class Abc {

    private static Map<Long, Abc> instances = new HashMap<Long, Abc>();

    //hiding the constructor
    private Abc() { }

    public static Abc getInstance() {
        Long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        if (!instances.containsKey(threadId)) {         
            instances.put(threadId, new Abc());
        }
        return instances.get(threadId);
    }

}
```